# Is this a correct way use powershell to get physical path of each site on a remote IIS server?

Tags: iis, powershell

I've been able to get the website names, ids and logfile locations from the remote server.  Finding the physical path of each sites root was less intuitive and is in the loop at the end of this message.  Is that the right way to access each sites physical path?  I'll need this to measure each sites disk usage.

```
[Void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Web.Administration")
$server = [Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager]::OpenRemote($machine)
$sites = $server.Sites #| Select Id, Name, LogFile

IF ( $sites.count -ne 0 ) 
{
    $logRootDir =$sites[0].LogFile.Directory
    write-host "log root dir = $logRootDir" 
}
ELSE 
{
    write-host "there are no IIS websites on this machine"
    Exit
}

foreach ($site in $sites) 
{
    write-host $site.Id $site.Name
    $rootApp = $site.Applications | where { $_.Path -eq "/" }
    $rootVdir = $rootApp.VirtualDirectories | where { $_.Path -eq "/" }
    write-host "root dir = " $rootVdir.PhysicalPath
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with this:

```
$lf = @{n='LogFile';e={Join-Path ($_.LogFile.Directory -replace '^%SystemDrive%','C:') "W3SVC$($_.Id)"}}
$pp = @{n='PhysicalPath';e={$_.Applications['/'].VirtualDirectories['/'].PhysicalPath}}

$server.Sites | Select Id,Name,$lf,$pp
```

Answer (score 0):

To save a tab separated list as a text file:

```
New-Item c:\sites.txt -type file -force
[Void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Web.Administration")
$sm = New-Object Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager
foreach($site in $sm.Sites)
{
    $root = $site.Applications | where { $_.Path -eq "/" }
    $rootVdir = $root.VirtualDirectories | where { $_.Path -eq "/" }
    Write-Output ($site.Name + "`t" + $site.State + "`t" + $rootVdir.PhysicalPath + "`t" + $site.Id + "`t" + $site.Bindings + "`t" + $root.ApplicationPoolName) >> c:\sites.txt
}
```